# Changing values from columns according to DataGridViewComboBoxCell

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell, datagridviewtextboxcell

I have the following `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` which is generated in execution time and inserted in a `DataGridView`:

```
    Public Sub GenerateCol()
        Try
            Col.DataSource = LoadData()
            Col.DisplayMember = "code"
            Col.ValueMember = "code"
            Col.Name = "col2"
            Col.HeaderText = "Column 2"
            Col.DataPropertyName = "col2"
            Col.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic
            dgv.Columns.Insert(15, Col)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("ERROR: " & vbCrLf & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

And this is the method which loads values into tha ComboBox Cells:

```
Private Function LoadData() As DataTable
    Try
        dt = sd.RunService("Service", DSResult) 'executes a sql string
        Return dt.Tables(0)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("No Data" & vbCrLf & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    End Try
End Function
```

Return output:

```
code  |  date | value
---------------------
A       12/06   100
B       12/06   200
...
```

However, I want to know which events I must use to change the values of two `DataGridViewNumericColumn`. One of these `dgvNumericColumn` must take the value of the datatable exposed, according to the value (code) displayed in the `ComboBoxCell`  and the date selected. The other column, must take that value and another value of a third column (I have to multiply those values).

I was thinking in `SelectedIndexChanged` event but I'm still working on it. It actually does nothing:

```
Private Sub Col_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim SelectedMon As Object
    Dim SelectedDiv = CType(Col.Selected, String)

    SelectedMon = dt.Tables(0).Columns("value")
    col_Mon.Value = col_Nom * SelectedMon
    col_valmon.Value = SelectedMon

End Sub
```

EDIT: I created a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49051322/databindings-datamember-error-when-firing-cellvaluechanged) about the `CellValueChanged` Event. It now fires but with problems. Thanks in advance

Comment: I have to point out that your comment… _”I want to know which events I must use to change the values of two DataGridViewNumericColumn. One of these dgvNumericColumn must take the value of the datatable exposed, according to the value (code) displayed in the ComboBoxCell and the date selected. The other column, must take that value and another value of a third column (I have to multiply those values).”_  … is very difficult to understand. You should clarify what you want to achieve.

Comment: @JohnG I want to change values of two numeric cells according of the selected value in the comboboxcell

Comment: If you were using a regular combo box then that would indicate you need to wire up the combo box’s `SelectedIndexChanged`. However, it appears you are using a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`, and unfortunately the `SelectedIndexChanged` event is not available since there are multiple combo boxes in the column. Therefore, to capture when one of the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` cells value changed, you can use the grids `CellValueChanged` event, If a cell value changes, simply check to see if it is one of the combo boxes, if it is, then, do the changes you described. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: When the `YourDataGridViewName_CellValueChanged` event fires… it will pass in a `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` object called `e`… it contains the location of the cell… `e.RowIndex` and `e.ColumnIndex`.

Comment: I added the event. However, it does not fire for some reason. I'm still investigating

Comment: I am betting that the event is being fired, unfortunately, the “if” statement will NEVER be entered because a `DataGridViewRow` will never equal a `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`. The `dgv.SelectedRows` is an array of grid “rows”… not “cells”. Bear in mind, you already KNOW the row and column indexes of the changed cell.

Comment: If you know the physical column index of the combo box column (example the first column in the grid - index = 0), then if `e.ColumnIndex = 0`, is true… this would indicate the combo box at row `e.RowIndex` and column `e.ColumnIndex` (0) changed value.

Comment: I created a new question about the event. Now it fires but it does not change my values in the other columns of the row. Thanks in advance