# DataMember Error when firing CellValueChanged

Tags: .net, vb.net, data-binding, datatable, datagridviewcomboboxcell

Following my anterior [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48998580/changing-values-from-columns-according-to-datagridviewcomboboxcell)  about changing values on column cells according a `comboboxcolumncells`, now I have the following problem. My event fires, but I get the following error message on the `DataBindings` line: **can't link the property or function "value" in DataSource. Parameter Name: dataMember**. Aside of that, the values of the other columns didn't changed. What should I do in this case?

```
   Private Sub dgv_CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv.CellValueChanged

        Dim r As Integer = e.RowIndex
        Dim c As Integer = e.ColumnIndex

        Try
            If r > -1 Then 
                If c = 15 Then
                    dgv.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "value", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged) 'I wanted to overwrite cells with the value associated with the code of the comboboxcell

                    Dim col_div_cell_value As Object = dt.Tables(0).Columns("value")

                    dgv.CurrentRow.Cells("col_1").Value = col_div_cell_value.Value()
                    dgv.CurrentRow.Cells("col_2").Value = (col_div_cell_value * col_3)

                End If
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("ERROR: " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

**dt's structure**: This `datatable` is charged into the `comboboxcell`, which displays the `"code"` and the value I want to write on the other columns cells of the row (Col_1 and Col_2), is the `"value"` associated to that code:

```
code  |  date | value
---------------------
A       12/06   100
B       12/06   200
...
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I didn't need to use `DataBindings`. Instead, I only assigned values to the fields of the columns `col_2` and `col_3`. This went more simpler than I thought :

```
Private Sub dgv_CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvBlotter.CellValueChanged
    Dim r As Integer = e.RowIndex
    Dim c As Integer = e.ColumnIndex

    Try
        If r > -1 Then 
            If c = 15 Then

                Dim flag As Double = dgv.CurrentRow.Cells("col2").Value 'name of comboboxcolumn
                Dim nuevovalor As Object = flag
                Dim nominal As Double = dgv.CurrentRow.Cells("col_3").Value

                dgv.CurrentRow.Cells("col_1").Value() = nuevovalor
                dgv.CurrentRow.Cells("col_2").Value() = (nuevovalor * nominal)

            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("ERROR: " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Clarify what is your dt?
Here you stating that there is a "value" property in it

```
dgv.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "value", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
```

And here you state that there is a Tables property, and inside the "0"-index table there is a "value".

```
Dim col_div_cell_value As Object = dt.Tables(0).Columns("value")
```

I think you should use dt.Tables(0) or something like it as datasource

Comment: my dt is a datatable with the structure posted above. I want to obtain (on the fly) the value associated to the code (which is selected in the combobox). The value is a column of that datatable. Sorry for my bad english